# awk automatically rounding off the output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

i used the below awk command

```
awk -F ':' '
  { s3 += $3; }
  { s4=s4+$4; }
  { s5=s5+$5; }
  END { print s3,","s4,","s5,","s3/s5 }' sample.txt > sample1.txt
```

And my input file (sample.txt) is:

```
05/05/2013:0:47623.49:1007:180
05/05/2013:1:35959.84:1959:132
05/05/2013:2:26317.05:690:85
05/05/2013:3:8715.40:107:32
05/05/2013:4:5713.27:66:24
05/05/2013:5:10533.34:1025:17
05/05/2013:6:10748.54:602:58
05/05/2013:7:44429.87:1644:203
05/05/2013:8:97096.44:4320:415
05/05/2013:9:148065.87:6603:639
05/05/2013:10:194488.19:8426:900
05/05/2013:11:231119.09:10991:986
05/05/2013:12:263701.11:10771:1070
05/05/2013:13:275892.40:10005:1054
05/05/2013:14:272595.88:9702:1120
05/05/2013:15:286506.75:10953:1110
05/05/2013:16:119102.11:4298:504
```

but the command is automatically rounding off, the output is:

```
2078610.00,83169 ,8529 ,243.711
```

I want the output as `2078609.56` (exact value without round off), how to achieve this in awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line:

```
 awk -F ':' '{ s3 += $3;s4+=$4;s5+=$5} END{ printf "%.2f,%d,%d,%f", s3,s4,s5,s3/s5 }' input
```

awk could specify the output format by using function `printf`. I notice that your $3 and the `$3/$5` may need special precision, I just add `%.2f and %f`, you could adjust it for your needs.

the output of the above line:

```
2078608.64,83169,8529,243.710709
```

i don't know how did you get the "exact value" `2078609.56` typo in your input file?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the default output format (`OFMT`) rounds to the first six most significant digits (`%.6g`). You can modify this value to `%.10f` to print 10 digits after decimal point. You can change the first line of Your command to:

```
awk -F ':' -vOFMT=%.10f '
```

Also to treat `s3/s5` as a float You should modify the `END` closure as

```
END { print s3,",",s4,",",s5,",",s3/s5 }'
```

There is two problems using this:

1. `OFMT` works only for float numbers. Numbers like `123` or `123.00` is considered as integers internally by awk, so they will be printed without using this variable. IMHO the output in the question should be something like this:

   2.07861e+06 , 83169 , 8529 , 243.711
2. Actually not the `2078609.56` value is the exact value. As the numbers are represented in binary form, they will be added as such. So if You set the output format to `%.10f` you will get something like this:

   2078608.6399999999 , 83169 , 8529 , 243.7107093446